# Apache Mod_rewrite condition with not condition

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, blogs

My file is here

```
PassengerMaxPoolSize 25
PassengerPoolIdleTime 10
<VirtualHost *:80>
      RailsEnv development
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /myapp/public
      <Directory /myapp/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride All
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
        RewriteEngine On
        ErrorDocument 503 /system/maintenance.html


#        RailsAllowModRewrite on

         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(home|book-club|blog|login|book-clubs|)$ [NC]
       RewriteRule .? http://blog.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]  
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
        RewriteRule ^/blog/?(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com/$1 [P,NC,R=301,L]
        ProxyPass         /blog/ http://blog.mysite.com/
          ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.mysite.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
  <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want when user hit `http:://www.mysite.com/home` or `http:://www.mysite.com/book-clubs` it redirect to mysite.com/home and  http:://www.mysite.com/book-clubs but `other than this it redirect to blog.myste.com/<Page-link>` Please some one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `/blog/` URL first and then check for `home`, `book-club`, etc.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ http://blog.mysite.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule !^/(home|book-club|login|book-clubs|)$ http://blog.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

You don't need the [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), you can check for the URL path as the pattern in the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

You also missed the leading slash when checking for `/home`, etc. Omit the slash only, when using `RewriteRule` inside a .htaccess file or `Directory` directive.

As a final note, never test with `R=301`, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.